# How can I see what kind of car charger I have?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb, battery, charging, car-dock

I noticed that when using navigation plus GPS my phone (Galaxy S2) still discharges a bit even so its connected to a car charger.

While googeling, I found out that regular USB chargers only charge with .1 amp but since a car battery isn't drained so easily, there are also car chargers that charge with .5 amp.

Is there a way see on the phone how much its beinbg charged with ? My phone only displays "USB" or "AC".

I'd like to find out if buying a "fast charger" would make any difference or if I already have a charger that supplies .5 amp.

Answer (score 3):

Look on the charger for where it says "output".  It'll say 5V, 0.5A or similar.

Comment: It doesn't say on the charger. I found the package it came in and it says 1000mA, but I have trouble believing it. It would rather see what Android thinks its getting.

Comment: Might try something like [current widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.currentwidget) to find out what android thinks its getting.  Not sure if it works on whatever GS2 variant you have or not.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, but it doesn't work on my GS2. Any other apps I could try ?

Comment: Try looking at the file /sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_current_adc while you're charging. That should say something about the charging current if the battery sensor supports it. If that says 0, you're basically SOL as far as finding anything out from software, as the sensor isn't reporting that information to the OS. The only other option would be to rig in an ammeter on the power line of a USB cord and measure the current directly